# jdbc:h2:file:./h2_db, tables don't exist.(springboot, jpa)

Tags: java, spring-boot, h2

I just made H2database file. but when I log in h2console. my tables don't show up.  am i missing something in application.yml?
[image]

```
spring:
  profiles: dev
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:file:./h2_db;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    username: root
    password: 1
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
      settings:
        web-allow-others: true
  jackson:
    serialization:
      fail-on-empty-beans: false
    deserialization:
      READ_UNKNOWN_ENUM_VALUES_USING_DEFAULT_VALUE: true
    jpa:
      database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
      hibernate:
        ddl-auto: update
      properties:
        hibernate:
          format_sql: true
          show_sql: true
          default_batch_fetch_size: 100
```

Comment: Can you post the SpringBoot application log?

Comment: are you seeing CREATE TABLE ... statements on your application log? If not, try to investigate why your @Entity classes are not being scanned by Spring JPA. Can you share more information about your package structure, the full app log etc?